# How to set action attribute with original URL?

Tags: html

In the following code, I hope to post the data to original URL, so I set blank for *action attribute* in  `<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id="myformID">`, the code works well.

But in IDE of VS Express for Web, the system report validation (XHTML5) warning : action attribute requires a value!

How can I fill in a value for the action attribute?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <script src="js/jquery1.10.2.min.js?isassets=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function () {

      $("#ToolBarDownload").click(function(){
           if (confirm('Do you want to Download')) {
              $("#myformID").submit();
           }
      });

      $("#myformID").submit( function(eventObj) {

           $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
              .attr('name', "myCw")
              .attr('value', "mydata")
              .appendTo('#myformID');

           return true;
        });
     });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

   <div id="container">

       <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id="myformID">

       </form>

       <span id="ToolBarDownload" class="ToolBarButton" style="margin-left:5px">Download</span>

   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any ideas for me?

Comment: any ideas for me?